# MongoDB: how to insert a sub-document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, subdocument

I am using sub-documents in my MEAN project, to handle orders and items per order.

These are my (simplified) schemas:

```js
var itemPerOrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  itemId: String,
  count: Number
});
```

```js
var OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  customerId: String,
  date: String,
  items: [ itemPerOrderSchema ]
});
```

To insert items in itemPerOrderSchema array I currently do:

```js
var orderId = '123';
var item = { itemId: 'xyz', itemsCount: 7 };
Order.findOne({ id: orderId }, function(err, order) {
  order.items.push(item);
  order.save();
});
```

The problem is that I obviously want one item per `itemId`, and this way I obtain many sub-documents per item...
One solution could be to loop through all `order.items`, but this is not optimal, of course (`order.items` could me **many**...).
The same problem could arise when querying `order.items`...

The question is: how do I insert items in `itemPerOrderSchema` array without having to loop through all items already inserted on the order?

Comment: itemPerOrder Schema has just items or items plus item id? I use similar format and I directly push elements into array, if you want the code then I can paste that here.

Comment: It has the itemid, too (`var itemPerOrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ itemId: String, ...`). If you can paste your code (in an answer, not in a comment, of course), it could help, for sure...

Comment: `modelname.findOneAndUpdate({_id: idname}, {$addToSet: { items: { $each: iems} }}, function(err, docs) {}` - This is what I do.

Comment: By `iems` you do mean `items`? But where is `item` to be inserted?

Comment: iems is item, spelling error - sorry. In my case iems is an array of string. You have to insert an object instead.

Comment: This might help you - http://www.journaldev.com/4334/mongodb-update-document-set-all-example-mongo-shell-java-driver

Comment: From MongoDb reference for $addToSet with $each: `You can use the $addToSet operator with the $each modifier. The $each modifier allows the $addToSet operator to add multiple values to the array field.`... But I don't need to add multiple values to the array field. I need to add an item to the array field if it's id is not present yet, and update the item in the array field if it is already present...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use an object instead of array for items, maybe you can change your schema a bit for a single-query update.

Something like this:

```
{
  customerId: 123,
  items: {
     xyz: 14,
     ds2: 7
  }
}
```

So, each itemId is a key in an object, not an element of the array.

```
let OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  customerId: String,
  date: String,
  items: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
});
```

Then updating your order is super simple. Let's say you want to add 3 of items number 'xyz' to customer 123.

```
db.orders.update({
  customerId: 123
},
{
  $inc: {
    'items.xyz': 3
  }
}, 
{
  upsert: true
});
```

Passing upsert here to create the order even if the customer doesn't have an entry.

The downsides of this:

- it is that if you use aggregation framework, it is either impossible to iterate over your items, or if you have a limited, known set of itemIds, then very verbose. You could solve that one with mapReduce, which can be a little slower, depending on how many of them you have there, so YMMB.
- you do not have a clean `items` array on the client. You could fix that with either client extracting this info (a simple `let items = Object.keys(order.items).map(key => ({ key: order.items[key] }));` or with a mongoose virtual field or schema.path(), but this is probably another question, already answered.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for... I didn't know about Schema.Types.Mixed... Thanks! I'm only a bit worried about aggregation framework issues, since I'm currently using it for querying... Though probably I will be able to avoid iterating over items on the server, but only on the client (I'll test order.items.map() to get the items...).

Comment: It's `Object.keys(order.items).map();`, but that's cool. Querying and aggregation works too, and depending on what you want, it can be done. But sometimes it can be a little verbose.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you probably need to add orderId to your itemPerOrderSchema because the combination of orderId and itemId will make the record unique.

Assuming that orderId is added to the itemPerOrderSchema, I would suggest the following implementation:

```
function addItemToOrder(orderId, newItem, callback) {
  Order.findOne({ id: orderId }, function(err, order) {
    if (err) {
        return callback(err);
    }

    ItemPerOrder.findOne({ orderId: orderId, itemId: newItem.itemId }, function(err, existingItem) {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err);
      }

      if (!existingItem) {
        // there is no such item for this order yet, adding a new one
        order.items.push(newItem);
        order.save(function(err) {
          return callback(err);
        });
      }

      // there is already item with itemId for this order, updating itemsCount
      itemPerOrder.update(
        { id: existingItem.id }, 
        { $inc: { itemsCount: newItem.itemsCount }}, function(err) {
            return callback(err);
        }
      );
    });   
  });
}

addItemToOrder('123', { itemId: ‘1’, itemsCount: 7 }, function(err) {
    if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  }
  console.log("Item successfully added to order");
});
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: Thanks! It will help, probably... However, I did hope to find some way to just call  order.save, after having updated order sub-document simply by pushing an element (or modifying it) to a javascript array...

Comment: Maybe use $inc instead of $set there for the `existingItem` update (provided count is integer) - in case you have concurrent updates.